# How do you associate a Page with an App, now that the migration deadline is over?

Tags: migration, profile, facebook-page

Here's the situation: I have a native iOS app that had its entry in created Facebook Developers before App Profile Pages were deprecated. There is an automatically created App Profile Page for the app, but when I view it, it has a yellow box saying:

> Removing App Profile Pages App Profile Pages are now deprecated. We
>   recommend updating any links that you have shared to your App Profile
>   Page to point to your new target Page or app. Please save any content
>   or Insights that you wish to keep. This content is accessible via the
>   Graph API with any valid access token. For additional information,
>   please review this post:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/02/01/how-to--migrate-your-app-profile-page/

Before February 1st, there was a link to migrate this page to a regular Facebook Page, but now there isn't. I've created a new Facebook Page according the the docs, and the page has the same name as the app and the category is set to Products/App. But I see no way to associate this new page with my app.

How are we supposed to associate a new Facebook Page with an existing app?

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to convert a page into an application page.  However in the blog post that you linked to there are details about how to open a page from within the app settings.  Have you tried creating a page from there?

Comment: Remember that Facebook is very strict about what you can and can't do and also when you are allowed do something with regard to changing major settings (such as what type of page it is, or the name of the page).  This is to prevent people from drastically changing a page's contents and meaning thereby confusing users who will think "But I didn't 'like' THAT!".

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up deleting my app on Facebook and creating a new one. This meant changing the App ID strings in my iOS app and in its URL handler, but now it works correctly, and I can create a normal Facebook Page for the app. If you have an existing app that customers are already using, that means you'll break the app unless they've updated it on their iOS device, and you lose everything on the old page.

Answer (score 0):

To associate an existing Facebook Page with an App:

1. Go to your Facebook Page and click "Edit Page" section
2. In the Basic Information tab, set Category as "Brands & Products" -> "App Page"

   - Make sure the Page name is the same as the App name
3. Go to your Facebook App "Edit App" page, and now you will be able to choose the Page as the App page.